# How to simply compile a php project in command line?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm totally new to php. I got a project to work on that I'm trying few stuff.

I have composer installed. I start my project like `php artisan serve`

I can access the server on port 8000
After doing some editing how should i compile it ?

Comment: You do not need to compile PHP, as PHP is interpreted language.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil So running again php artisan serve, will have all changes?

Comment: You don't have to run the `php artisan serve` again, just refresh the page, most of the time your change will there. If not, clear cache and you are good

Comment: Are you talking about compiling the javascript and css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compile PHP because PHP is an interpreted or you can say scripting Language.

As soon as you save the changes and reload the browser changes will be reflected

you do not need to hit the command `php artisan serve` again and again